# nix-build nix-generate-from-cpan: expression does not evaluate to a derivation

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

I'm trying to use [nix-generate-from-cspan](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-generation-from-CPAN) to install [sqitch](http://sqitch.org/#cpan)

From `nix-generate-from-cpan App::Sqitch DBD::Pg`, I made this file:

```
{buildPerlModule, fetchurl}:
buildPerlModule rec {
    name = "App-Sqitch-0.9995";
    src = fetchurl {
        url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/D/DW/DWHEELER/${name}.tar.gz";
        sha256 = "c29b4610ce43bd43ecfa39188f4cbb00b38c390136fcdd9984142efd99eba292";
    };
    buildInputs = [ CaptureTiny ModuleBuild TestDeep TestDir TestException TestFile TestFileContents TestMockModule TestNoWarnings ];
    propagatedBuildInputs = [ Clone ConfigGitLike DBI DateTime DateTimeTimeZone DevelStackTrace EncodeLocale FileHomeDir HashMerge IOPager IPCRun3 IPCSystemSimple ListMoreUtils Moo PathClass PerlIOutf8_strict StringFormatter StringShellQuote SubExporter TemplateTiny Throwable TryTiny TypeTiny URI URIdb libintlperl namespaceautoclean self."if" ];
    meta = {
        homepage = http://sqitch.org/;
        description = "Sane database change management";
        license = stdenv.lib.licenses.mit;
    };
}
```

but running `nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> { }; callPackage ./sqitch.nix'` gives this error:

```
expression does not evaluate to a derivation (or a set or list of those)
```

To debug, I tried `nix-instantiate --eval --expr 'with import <nixpkgs> { }; callPackage ./sqitch.nix'` which gives:

```
<LAMBDA>
```

So I tried `nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> { }; callPackage callPackage ./sqitch.nix'` but it still gives the same error, and `nix-instantiate --eval --expr 'with import <nixpkgs> { }; callPackage callPackage ./sqitch.nix'` gives:

```
{ __functor = <CODE>; override = <CODE>; overrideDerivation = <CODE>; }
```

which does not help me much.

Comment: Aaand I forgot adding `{}` after my `callPackage`s. That explains a lot of things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

the result of `buildPerlModule` is meant to be used as `src` in `mkDerivation` params.

### Long answer

It turns out `sqitch` is already part of nixpkgs, and it is defined like this:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/56904d7c423f2b13b37fbd29f39bbb4b52bc7824/pkgs/development/tools/misc/sqitch/default.nix

```
{ name, stdenv, perl, makeWrapper, sqitchModule, databaseModule }:

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "${name}-${sqitchModule.version}";

  buildInputs = [ perl makeWrapper sqitchModule databaseModule ];

  src = sqitchModule;
  dontBuild = true;

  installPhase = ''
    mkdir -p $out/bin
    for d in bin/sqitch etc lib share ; do
      ln -s ${sqitchModule}/$d $out/$d
    done
  '';
  dontStrip = true;
  postFixup = "wrapProgram $out/bin/sqitch --prefix PERL5LIB : $PERL5LIB";

  meta = {
    platforms = stdenv.lib.platforms.unix;
  };
}
```

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/56904d7c423f2b13b37fbd29f39bbb4b52bc7824/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix#L10116-L10120

```
  sqitchPg = callPackage ../development/tools/misc/sqitch {
    name = "sqitch-pg";
    databaseModule = perlPackages.DBDPg;
    sqitchModule = perlPackages.AppSqitch;
  };
```

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/56904d7c423f2b13b37fbd29f39bbb4b52bc7824/pkgs/top-level/perl-packages.nix#L281-L305 (which is the output of `nix-generate-from-cpan App::Sqitch`)

```
 AppSqitch = buildPerlModule rec {
    version = "0.9994";
    name = "App-Sqitch-${version}";
    src = fetchurl {
      url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/D/DW/DWHEELER/${name}.tar.gz";
      sha256 = "0in602z40s50fdlmws4g0a1pb8p7yn0wx8jgsacz26a4i1q7gpi4";
    };
    buildInputs = [
      CaptureTiny PathClass TestDeep TestDir TestException
      TestFile TestFileContents TestMockModule TestNoWarnings
    ];
    propagatedBuildInputs = [
      Clone ConfigGitLike DBI DateTime
      DevelStackTrace EncodeLocale FileHomeDir HashMerge IOPager IPCRun3
      IPCSystemSimple ListMoreUtils Moo PathClass PerlIOutf8_strict StringFormatter
      StringShellQuote SubExporter TemplateTiny Throwable TryTiny TypeTiny URI
      URIdb libintlperl namespaceautoclean
    ];
    doCheck = false;  # Can't find home directory.
    meta = {
      homepage = http://sqitch.org/;
      description = "Sane database change management";
      license = stdenv.lib.licenses.mit;
    };
  };
```

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/56904d7c423f2b13b37fbd29f39bbb4b52bc7824/pkgs/top-level/perl-packages.nix#L3555-L3558

```
  DBDPg = import ../development/perl-modules/DBD-Pg {
    inherit stdenv fetchurl buildPerlPackage DBI;
    inherit (pkgs) postgresql;
  };
```

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/56904d7c423f2b13b37fbd29f39bbb4b52bc7824/pkgs/development/perl-modules/DBD-Pg/default.nix (which looks like the output of `nix-generate-from-cpan DBD::Pg`, but not exactly)

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, buildPerlPackage, DBI, postgresql }:

buildPerlPackage rec {
  name = "DBD-Pg-3.5.3";

  src = fetchurl {
    url = "mirror://cpan/authors/id/T/TU/TURNSTEP/${name}.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "03m9w1cd0yyrbqwkwcl92j1cpmasmm69f3hwvcrlfsi5fnwsk63y";
  };

  buildInputs = [ postgresql ];
  propagatedBuildInputs = [ DBI ];

  makeMakerFlags = "POSTGRES_HOME=${postgresql}";

  meta = {
    homepage = http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/;
    description = "DBI PostgreSQL interface";
    license = with stdenv.lib.licenses; [ artistic1 gpl1Plus ];
    platforms = stdenv.lib.platforms.unix;
  };
}
```

So that's how it is meant to be used.

NB : as I just noted in the comments of my question, I also forgot to add `{}` after my `callPackage`s, which explains the weird types I was getting.